# Finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Show that if a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is reflexive as a Banach space, then $A$ must be finite dimentional.

I tried to solve it; but, I could not. please help me for this exercise. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/112872/822) is related.

Answer (score 6):

> **Lemma 0.** Let maximal abelian $^*$-subalgebra $M$ of $C^*$ algebra $A$ which is finite dimensional, then
>   (i) $M$ is a linear span of finite family of  projections $\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}\subset A$ such that $p_i p_j=0$.
>   (ii) $A$ is finite dimensional.

See exercise 4.6.12 in *Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras. Vol.1. Elementary theory. R. V. Kadison, J. R. Ringrose*.

> **Lemma 1.** Any infinite dimensional $C^*$-algebra $A$ contains selfadjoint element with infinite spectrum.

Since $A$ is infinite dimensional by lemma 0, so does its maximal abelian $^*$-subalgebra $M$. Therefore there is infinite family of pairwise orthogonal projections $\{p_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now define $a=\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} p_n$. Since $a p_k=2^{-k}p_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\{2^{-k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \sigma(a)$. Hence $\sigma(a)$ is infinite. For details also see [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/the-spectrum-of-normal-operators-in-c-algebras).

> **Lemma 2.** Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact space, and $C_0(\Omega)$ is reflexive, then $\Omega$ is finite.

I'll borrow the main idea from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250325/space-of-bounded-functions-is-reflexive-if-the-domain-is-finite). Assume $\Omega$ is infinite, then we have infinite sequence of distinct point $(\omega_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Consider sequence of linear functionals $\delta_n:C_0(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}:f\mapsto f(\omega_n)$ of norm $1$ and an isometric operator $I:\ell_1\to C(\Omega)^*: a\mapsto \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\delta_n$. Thus we may regard $\ell_1$ as closed subspace of $C(\Omega)^*$. Sicne $C_0(\Omega)$ is reflexive, then from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341032/if-a-normed-space-x-is-reflexive-show-that-x-is-reflexive) we know that so does $C(\Omega)^*$.  Now we see that $\ell_1$ is reflexive [as closed subspace](http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/closed-subspaces-of-a-reflexive-space/) of reflexive $C_0(\Omega)^*$. Contradiction, hence $\Omega$ is finite.

> **Proposition.** Any reflxive $C^*$-algebra $A$ is finite dimensional.

Assume $A$ is infinite dimensional, then by lemma 1 we have a positive element $a\in A$ with infinite spectrum. Consider commutative $C^*$ subalgebra $C^*(a)$ generated by $a$. Since $C^*(a)$ is a closed subspace of reflxive space, then it is also reflexive [as closed subspace of reflexive  space](http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/closed-subspaces-of-a-reflexive-space/). From [this aswer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530081/confusion-in-gelfand-theorem-in-c-algebra/530525) we know that $C^*(a)\cong_1 C_0(\sigma(a)\setminus\{0\})$, hence $C_0(\sigma(a)\setminus\{0\})$ is reflexive. By lemma 2 we get that $\sigma(a)\setminus\{0\}$ is finite and so does $\sigma(a)$. Contradiction, hence $A$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Why is the maximal abelian *-subalgebra  infinite?

Comment: @mathrookie, I fixed the statement of the lemma. Now it must be clear that $M$ is infinite-dimensional